# Dynamic Column Visibility in ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm still fairly new to Angular (5.2.4 to be specific), and I'm struggling with something that I hope someone could shed some light on for me...

I'm tinkering with the ngx-datatable library and I'm trying to create a datatable. I can get the basic examples working, but for some reason I'm not able to figure out why I can't get a feature from one example to work in another.

What I mean is, if I take the source code here: http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#inline-edit and get it working, I can't seem to then code the ability to toggle the visibility of the inline editable column example like in this one: http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#toggle

Can anyone help nudge me in the right direction? I feel like I'm overlooking something basic (maybe I just need more coffee...).